# How to create a webservice which listens to tfs 2010 event alerts?

Tags: web-services

i need a webservice which listens to tfs (2010). The tfs will trigger an alert when build quality is changed. i want to process that SOAP message using a webservice. how do i create that? is there any template? i am a rookie in c# &.net...it would be much helpful if someone gives me a template...thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a WCF service to receive these alerts. Please see ["How to use WCF to subscribe to the TFS 2010 Event Service [rolling up hours]"](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx).

Comment: when i write the code visual studio says "Invalid token ':' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" for the line "[OperationContract(Action = http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Notification/03/Notify)]" in the link any idea why?thx

Comment: You have to surround the URI with quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using this method for using WCF event handlers, I would actually use the new [ISubscriber](http://colinsalmcorner.blogspot.com/2011/12/isubscriber-getting-tfs-url-for-client.html) method.  We additionally discuss how it works in Chapter 25 of our book, [Professional Team Foundation Server 2010](http://bit.ly/TFS2010Book) by Wrox.

Answer (score 2):

Web services generally make a request, get a response, and leave. They don't hang around listening.

**TFS is capable of sending notifications**. It's a fairly simple process. For starters, here is a [how-to article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-configure-tfs-notifications-in-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx) that says:

> TFS notifications are useful in sending alerts when a work item is changed, the build is completed, build property changed etc.

**Edit**: TFS offers several types of alerts, including email and SOAP, as explained in this posting on [How To Subscribe to TFS Alerts](http://development.meritsolutions.com/matters/how-to-subscribe-to-tfs-alerts/) which states:

> Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) contains a collection of services including version control, work item tracking, and the EventService service. EventService exposes a set of events that performs actions such as sending e-mail or a **SOAP-based Web service call**.

and a bit more

> If you want to get notified for all new workitems, regardless of who
>   they get assigned to, you will want a custom subscription...First option is to create alert with the BisSubscribe tool ... the preferred message delivery type: EmailHtml, EmailPlaintext, or SOAP. Default is SOAP.

Comment: I guess downvoting other people's answers helps you to get votes for your answer. In this instance, I have suggested a much simpler alternative approach, which seemed appropriate for someone who acknowledges being a rookie. Sometimes folks are not aware of all of their options.

Comment: I downvoted because the OP said nothing about wanting to receive emails.

Comment: I did not mention email, John.

Comment: Ok, thought you meant emails when you said TFS can send alerts. Still, the OP knows that TFS can send alerts through SOAP. He wants to know how to write a service that will receive those alerts.

Answer (score 2):

The open source project [TFS Global Alerts](http://tfsalerts.codeplex.com/) implements just that. You can [browse](http://tfsalerts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) the code and use it as a template.