# Team Foundation Server java notification

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk, team-explorer-everywhere

Is there any possibility for my Java (EE) application to get notified by the Team Foundation Server when a Build or Test Run is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Depending on the TFS server version you can use the Service Hooks option](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/service-hooks/services/webhooks) to configure a web service to be called when specific events happen. This featrue was introduced with TFS 2015.

[If you're on an older version you can configure an alert and instead of configuring it to use an email endpoint, point it to a SOAP webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064873/how-to-create-a-webservice-which-listens-to-tfs-2010-event-alerts). This technology is considered deprecated, but it still works.

I'm unsure whether Test Runs are explicitly included in these alert options.